# ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='cdn-lfs.huggingface.co', port=443): Read timed out

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, huggingface, huggingface-tokenizers, huggingface-hub

While running the code, model stops loading in between and gives the following error.

```
    from getpass import getpass
    import os
    HUGGINGFACE_API_TOKEN = getpass()
    os.environ[HUGGINGFACE_API_TOKEN] = HUGGINGFACE_API_TOKEN
    from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM
    from transformers import AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM, AutoTokenizer
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf")
    model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf")
```

### Downloading shards: 0%
0/2 [07:07<?, ?it/s]
Downloading (…)of-00002.safetensors: 29%
2.86G/9.98G [07:03<17:15, 6.87MB/s]

TimeoutError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/response.py:438, in HTTPResponse._error_catcher(self)
437 try:
--> 438     yield
440 except SocketTimeout:
441     # FIXME: Ideally we'd like to include the url in the ReadTimeoutError but
442     # there is yet no clean way to get at it from this context.

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/models.py:822, in Response.iter_content..generate()
820     raise ContentDecodingError(e)
821 except ReadTimeoutError as e:
--> 822     raise ConnectionError(e)
823 except SSLError as e:
824     raise RequestsSSLError(e)

ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='cdn-lfs.huggingface.co', port=443): Read timed out.

Can Someone Help me to load the model?